# How to cornucopia with deadpool_postgres / tokio_postgres

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres, cornucopia

I'm following the [Rust on Nail](https://rust-on-nails.com/docs/database-part-1/database-access/) guide to setup the project. It uses cornucopia to generate rust code from SQL queries, and deadpool_tokio / tokio_postgres for client.

When running the test to check DB connection, i'm getting the following error:

`` error[E0277]: the trait bound `deadpool::managed::Object<Manager>: cornucopia_async::GenericClient` is not satisfied ``

I'm using the exact same code as shown in the link, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Shot in the dark: you should double-check what version of deadpool-postgres you are using. Cornucopia has integrations for deadpool-postgres v10.0 but the latest is v11.0 which isn't compatible.